# Determining which resource is causing SSL warning in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I have a website with an SSL cert, but instead of displaying a green lock, google chrome shows a lock with a red cross on it and displays a warning that the page has insecure contents.

I understand that the cause of this is when you use a resource (image, js, css) that is not being brought over via HTTPS.

I have checked the 'net' tab in firebug, and every resource is over HTTPS. Thus I cannot figure out what is causing the warning in google chrome.

Is there a way to find out which specific resource is causing this to happen?

could it be the database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had Chrome cache issues with this before. If you're sure you've nabbed all the culprits try clearing your cache and history.