# Chrome localhost SSL security warning for Visual Studio 2013 web projects

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, visual-studio-2013

I recently started getting an orange triangle on the lock symbol when testing my VS2013 SSL websites from localhost in Chrome. Clicking on it shows up this message:

`This site is using outdated security settings that may prevent future versions of Chrome from being able to safely access it.`

Research indicates it is caused by SHA-1 being gradually deprecated, to be replaced by SHA-2. How do I change the VS2013 (or IIS Express) settings to encrypt using SHA-2?

Comment: I wish to know how to do this as well. @Krishna Gupta, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @paul no I wasn't able to. But please check out this answer - it might be a different problem and may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776006/determining-which-resource-is-causing-ssl-warning-in-chrome?rq=1